# How can I speed up regex querying in PostgreSQL database with django

Tags: python, regex, django, postgresql

I am trying to create regex query to my PostgreSQL database. I have already done it, but the problem is that the query with regex is up to 3 times slower than the query where I search by the name. Is there any way to accelarate regex query or any other option to get results faster? I use django to create queries to the database.

My "normal" query where I search car by brand and model:

```
object_db = Car.objects.filter(brand='Ford', car_model='Focus-RS')
```

I create regex query like this:

```
object_db = Car.objects.filter(brand__regex=r'^Ford$', car_model__regex='^Focus[-_]*RS$')
```

My model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_data = models.ForeginKey(CarData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
         index_together = (
             ('brand', 'car_model')
         )
```

I get the result that I want but it take to much time to get it. How can I improve the speed of regex query or is there any other method for the same results?

Comment: These regexps are fast as is. If you are not satisfied, switch to a non-regex method.

Comment: Have you indexed `brand` and `car_model` together?

Comment: What do you mean by that? @dirkgroten

Comment: You can use `icontains` as well: `Car.objects.filter(brand__icontains="Ford", car_model__icontains='Focus')`

Comment: Is there any other option to get the same results without regex? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Regardless whether you query with regex or not, you should always think about indexing your database for the queries you're planning to perform. If you're going to query for a match on two fields, you should use [**index_together**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.index_together). Don't forget to make migrations after changing indexes.

Comment: `r'^Ford$'` ... and the point of this "regex" is?.. Change this back to equality filter.

Comment: It is just the example. @IvanStarostin

Comment: It speed up my queries but regex is still to slow to for me. @dirkgroten

Comment: @MihaelWaschl maybe you can add your model definition so that people know about how the field is represented in the database.

Comment: @BernhardVallant I added it.

Comment: If you show the real regex you’re using we might give you an alternative. The expression you use now doesn’t make sense to use a regex since you can just use =. Also you should compare the speed between `contains` and regex, not between exact match and regex. Exact match will always be much faster.

Comment: `car_model__startswith='Focus', car_model__endswith='RS'` did you try it?

Comment: In my database can be car_model with name focus_RS or focus-RS then user want to search this car_model in the database and he use focus RS (in this case I split string and add it to the regex). If I use the query without regex it will return no cars founded so I need the regex or user have to use foucus_RS or focus-RS. This is just the example it can be other cars too. @dirkgroten

Comment: How are you going to determine which regex to apply to which car model name? Note, you've made a typo in the last comment `foucus_RS` which is a very nice demonstration of what kind of mistakes users can make. And it is not solvable by regex. This is called **fuzzy search**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iexact` and combine queries using `Q`:

```
object_db = Car.objects.filter(
    brand__iexact="ford", 
    Q(car_model__iexact="focus-rs") | Q(car_model__iexact="focus_rs"))
```

This will match case-insensitive and perform an 'OR' query on the `car_model` field.

Comment: I assume given that this was chosen as the correct answer that the `*` in the original query was not needed by OP